# Image is pixelated during CGAffineTransform scale animation

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to mimic the Twitter launch screen, the issue I have is that, whether I use a system icon or a named SVG image, while I animate the scaling of the image to get that "zoom in" effect, the image is getting pixelated, which is reasonable since I scale it.
So that brings the question, is there a way to scale up the image in a way that won't damage the quality? so the scaling animation will not look pixelated when the image is scaled up?

---

Example of the issue:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Using PDF instead.

Comment: Extract the shape path as UIBezierPath using PocketSVG or other tools, then make the shape as CAShapeLayer with the path. Then you can scale up and down (shape or the path) as needed.

Comment: @Asteroid Thank you, using PocketSVG did solve my issue, and much more!
If you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround would be to draw the Twitter icon using UIBezierPath. You can use the ready-to-use [PocketSVG](https://github.com/pocketsvg/PocketSVG) library. It will give you an array of paths which you can combine and then add it to a CAShapeLayer. With that you can then apply transformation to the shape or path as you wish without worry about the quality.